# ¿Cómo realizó una comprensión de este código en Python?

Tags: lista, python-3.7, eliminar, repetidos, elementos

quiero hacer una comprensión de listas para que me arroje el mismo resultado con menos código. lo que hace el código es imprim las letras [ g a t o p e r c n j ] es decir, con los primeros dos for logro está lista [ 'g','a','t','o','p','e','r','r','o','c','o','n','e'',j'',o'] está lista ahora almacenada en la variable llamada lista_letras, quiero que guarde en la variable resultado solo las palabras que no se repitan ['g','a','t:','o','p','e','r','c','n','j'] con el código anterior lo puedo ejecutar pero ahora quiero realizarle una comprensión de listas al codigo.

```
lista_palabras = ["gato","perro","conejo"]
lista_letras = [ ]
resultado = [ ]
for una_palabra in lista_palabras:
 for una_letra in una_palabra:
  lista_letras.append(una_letra)
  #quiero una letra de la var lista_letras
for letra in lista_letras: 
  #si la letra no esta en la var resultado
 if letra not in resultado:
  #se agrega la letra a la var resultado
  resultado.append(letra)
  #solo se almacenan las letras que no esten en la variable y listo
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si tu pregunta tiene solo codigo, no tiene mucho sentido. Que es lo que estas preguntando?

Comment: Bien recibido el consejo, quiero hacer una comprensión de listas para que me arroje el mismo resultado con menos código. lo que hace el código es imprim las letras [ g a t o p e r c n j ] es decir, con los primeros dos for logro está lista [ 'g','a','t','o','p','e','r','r','o','c','o','n','e'',j'',o'] está lista ahora almacenada en la variable llamada lista_letras, quiero que se guarde en la variable resultado solo las palabras que no se repitan ['g','a','t:','o','p','e','r','c','n','j'] con el código anterior lo puedo ejecutar pero ahora quiero realizarle una comprensión de listas al codigo

Comment: Toda esa explicacion, en la pregunta. usa el boton [edit] y explica todo eso ahi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podras hacerlo asi y no ocupas "lista_letras"

```
lista_palabras = ["gato","perro","conejo"]
resultado = [ ]
for una_palabra in lista_palabras:
    for una_letra in una_palabra:
        #si la letra no esta en la var resultado
        if una_letra not in resultado:
            #se agrega la letra a la var resultado
            resultado.append(una_letra)
            #solo se almacenan las letras que no esten en la variable y listo
print(resultado)
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede hacerse en una sola línea y sin comprensiones de listas!

```
resultado = list(set("".join(lista_palabras)))
```

Y se obtiene:

```
['p', 'r', 'j', 'c', 'g', 't', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'a']
```

### Cómo funciona

Primero se juntan todas las palabras de `lista_palabras` en una sola cadena, usando `"".join(lista_palabras)`.

Después, esa única cadena resultante (que sería `"gatoperroconejo"`) se le pasa a `set()`. Se trata de un constructor de conjuntos. Los conjuntos son tipos de datos python que guardan elementos sin repetición (es decir, si un dato ya estaba en el conjunto, no se añade otra vez). El constructor `set()` espera un iterable como argumento, y le estamos pasando una cadena, que es en efecto un iterable. Así que `set()` itera por cada elemento de esa cadena y la va añadiendo al conjunto.

El conjunto resultante de ahí ya tiene las letras, sin repetición, que buscabas. El paso final es convertir ese resultado a lista. Este paso final en realidad podría omitirse según lo que pretendas hacer luego con esas letras. Un conjunto es también iterable, y admite el operador `in` para saber si una letra está o no está en él. Lo que no admite es la sintaxis de corchetes. Por ejemplo `conjunto[0]` no sirve para acceder al primer elemento del conjunto, porque *los conjuntos no están ordenados de ninguna forma* y por tanto no tiene sentido hablar de su primer o último elemento.

#### Nota sobre rendimiento

Mirar si un elemento está ya en un conjunto es mucho más rápido que mirar si está en una lista, por la forma en que están implementados los conjuntos. Esto hace que la solución propuesta sea mucho más rápida que la que tenías en la pregunta.

Como curiosidad, la solución iterando con bucles y listas tarda unos  4.33 µs en ejecutarse sobre esa lista de tres palabras. La solución propuesta con conjuntos tarda 0.86 µs

En listas con más palabras la diferencia sería aún mayor.